# Django select all models with foreign key

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

In A Django web app I have defined a model named Server

```
class Server(models.model):
```

and a bunch of models that use this model as a foreign key

```
class ServerInfo(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(server, null=True)
class ServerDNSRecord(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey(server, null=True)
...etc
```

Now what I have an API call that returns a server with all of its attached info. Currently I am just doing a for loop for each server and searching each info table with the name of the server. The problem is sometimes I need to make an API call that returns ALL of the servers and their info.

This creates a huge amount of SQL Queries to the database, and the response time on this call is usually greater than 5 seconds, which is unacceptable.

Is there any easy way to do some sort of join or foreign key search to decrease the amount of database calls to speed things up?

Comment: `select_related` might be what you want: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to perform a select_related on all the related types you're going to be grabbing. For instance:

```
res = Server.objects.prefetch_related("serverinfo_set", "serverdnsrecord_set", ...).first()
res.serverinfo_set # Won't need another query
res.serverdnsrecord_set # Won't need another query
```

Also, if you want to do this automagically you could do:

```
related_fieldnames = [f.get_accessor_name() for f in Server._meta.get_all_related_objects()]
res = Server.objects.prefetch_related(*related_fieldnames).first()
res.serverinfo_set # Won't need another query
res.serverdnsrecord_set # Won't need another query
```

I should point out that if this application gets reused and someone starts tacking on more ForeignKeys to Server that those will all get select_related of course.

Comment: I am confused because on the django documentation it seems like select_related is used for the opposite of what I want to do. that is you give select related the model with the foreign key and it finds the model table. I am also getting an error stating that Query_Set has no attribute find_one so I don't think that is a valid method.

Comment: @Josh Whoops, meant first() not find_one(), too much mongodb.

Comment: Also, your comment about the documentation is accurate, it's a bit confusing. But iirc select_related just operates on the same names that you would use after a `.` to access the data and uses `__` anywhere where you would use a `.` thereafter (like `res.serverinfo_set.someother_foreign_key` would be `serverinfo_set__someother_foreign_key`

Comment: So in my Server model I have a foreign key reference to a datacenter. I am getting an error from using my select_related saying that datacenter is the only option avaliable.

Comment: @Josh Hmm, you're right. Apparently that's what prefetch_related is for. Wonder if they changed that or if I just never knew.

Comment: this does not work either. did you try running this on a test app? It seems that there are no ORM methods for what I need to do.

Comment: Sorry, no I haven't. Do you mean to say that it's taking too long, or that it's not working at all?

Comment: Ok, if your problem is with the second bit of code, I just fixed it, if the first one didn't work then you need to be more specific because it works for me.

Comment: so for either one, when i try to print the res.<foreignkey>_set i get <foreignkey>_set.None But i can print res.name, so I know it i fetching the server just not the related stuff

Comment: interesting, doing this, : from pprint import pprint
    pprint (vars(res)) I can see that all of the related objects are there, just under _prefetched_objects_cache, interesting. will look more.

Comment: ah so I have it figured out now, had to do Server.serverinfo_set.all(), so for me I had to add the .all()

Comment: Oh, yes, technically it is a queryset not a list of objects. That was sort of more pseudo code then actual code.